# Why can't I create a setup file inside my solution?

Tags: visual-studio, project

I want to edit registry in visual studio. To do that I have to create a setup project to access it. SO I went to visual studio -> My solution -> Add -> new project but I can't find setup project in the Templates. Why and what can I do?

Comment: You forgot to mention the version of VS which you are using, but [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) might be useful to you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Visual Studio 2015